# SignalR in android

Tags: c#, android, signalr

I create signal and it not run. I want to click button in app 1 and app 2 textview set "Nam". But
Click button in app 1. text view show connect. but app 2 is not set text 'Nam'.
Click button on app 2. It show Nam. 
Signal in C# is correct. this is my code

```java
    TextView textView;
    HubConnection hubConnection;
    String user ="Nam";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://10.0.2.2:5000/chatHub").build();
        hubConnection.start();

        hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user) -> {
            textView.setText(user);
        }, String.class);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(hubConnection.getConnectionState()== HubConnectionState.CONNECTED){
            textView.setText("Connect");
            hubConnection.send("SendMessage",user);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe what you expect to happen as well as what is currently happening.  What is the Error?

Comment: Hi you. I open 2 emulation apps. Click button in app 1. Nothing happen. Then i click to button in app 2. Text view in app 2 show "Nam". I dont know why