# Disconnected when send request to SignalR server

Tags: java, c#, android

I make a signalR server and I using android studio to send and receive request But when i send request to server. It is disconnected.
It is onCreate

```
    textView =findViewById(R.id.textView);
    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://10.0.2.2:5000/chatHub").build();

    hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage",(user)->{
        textView.setText(user);
    },String.class);

    hubConnection.start();
```

It is on button click to send request

```
    user = "Nam";
    //signalRListener.sendToServer(user);
    if(hubConnection.getConnectionState()== HubConnectionState.CONNECTED){
        hubConnection.send("SendMessage",user);
        textView.setText("Sent");

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [SignalR in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652291/signalr-in-android) which was written by the same user.

Comment: But nobody care

Comment: Then [edit] the question to make it more inviting and answerable...